# MySQL find if one column contains any values of another column

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

| ID | business_name | district |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dhaka bank | cumilla |
| 2 | cumilla dodhi | rajshahi |
| 3 | maloncha | dhaka |
| 4 | dhaka bank | dhaka |

I need the query to find the business name that contains any district

| ID | business_name | district |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dhaka bank | cumilla |
| 2 | cumilla dodhi | rajshahi |
| 4 | dhaka bank | dhaka |

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: it would be better if you show us your table structure and sample data rather that your desired output only.

Comment: Already shown in the first portion

Comment: oh. you mean the first table is your actual table and the second table is your desired output?

Comment: Yes, You are right

Comment: Have you already tried to group by your `district` column?

Answer (score 3):

Use exists logic along with word boundaries:

```sql
SELECT ID, business_name, district
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM yourTable t2
    WHERE t1.business_name REGEXP CONCAT('\\b', t2.district, '\\b')
    -- Note: On MySQL 5.7 and earlier use:
    -- WHERE t1.business_name REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]', t2.district, '[[:>:]]')
);
```

Comment: My table contains 1M rows. Its taking too much time

Comment: Great answer because of also showing the usage in older MySQL versions

Comment: How often do you need to run this query?  Consider just running it once, and then changing your table design to check for a matching district before inserting.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Since it's quite resource-consuming, should we make another table to store the result set as well as create a trigger on the original table to perform the check on new inserts and record in the new table if the condition is met ?

Comment: @blabla_bingo That sounds like one viable option.